# react-dropdown - display will not change if setState is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React form. I'm using the react-dropdown dependency. I'm having a very strange issue. There is an onChange prop passed to the dropdown component. When is comes back, it sends the value from the dropdown menu back up to the parent component (the form in my case).

One would THINK you could take that response and set its value to the state via `this.setState()`.

Except when I use `setState()`, in any way, the display value for the select menu stops changing. It shows me my `Select your Business` text instead of the selected value. If I remove the `setState()`, it changes.

What.....?

Here is a trimmed down version of the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown'
import FormInput from '../FormInput/FormInput'; 
import FormCheckbox from '../FormCheckbox/FormCheckbox'; 
import './RegistrationForm.css'
import 'react-dropdown/style.css'

export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state={ 
            error_business_name: false,
            error_business_email: false,
            error_username: false, 
            error_password: false, 
            error_type: false, 
            error_terms: false, 
            error_policy: false, 
            email: null,
            business_name: null, 
            username: null, 
            password: null, 
            website: null, 
            terms: false 
        }
    }



    handleSelect(e) {
        console.log(e.value)
        this.setState({ type: e.value })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <main role="main" className="RegistrationForm">
                <img alt="Simplr Logo" src={require("../../images/logo.png")} />
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>

                    <section className={this.state.error_type ? "error" : ""}>
                        <label htmlFor="type">Type of Business</label> 
                        <Dropdown 
                            className={this.state.error_type ? "dropdown error-dropdown" : "dropdown"} 
                            options={["Law Office", "Accounting Firm", "Construction"]} 
                            // onChange={e => this.setState({ type: e.value })} 
                            onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e)} 
                            placeholder="Select your Business" id="type"
                        />
                        <p className="error-message">Please select a valid business type</p>
                    </section>

                    <button>REGISTER</button>
                </form>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

`handleSelect()` gets called on change. If I remove `this.setState({ type: e.value })` from that method, the display changes. But if I put it in, I can still get the value, but the display then won't change from the default `Select your Business` text. The value gets set to the state, but it doesn't appear to be selected to the user.

I have no idea how these two processes are even connected. To my mind, once things are sent off to `handleSelect()`, the dropdown's job is over. But clearly, the `setState()` part is impacting the dropdown.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React dropdown component needs an array of objects as options [{label : "", value : ""}]

So instead of passing a string array pass an array of objects and set whole selected object as state and assign the selected state to value in Dropdown.

Comment: I really want to understand what you just said, but I'm struggling a little bit. I am new to this dependency. I don't understand how something that is passed down impacts what happens when the value is passed back up.

Comment: I tried passing objects, and it doesn't change anything. Same issue when I try to set state

Comment: Actually you have passed a string array as options in react dropdown component, instead of it you need to pass [{label: "Law Office", value : "law_office"},...] An array of objects similar to it, because I have used react dropdown component and it requires this kind of pattern as options and when the selection is changed it provides the selected object in return so if you assign the selected object returned by dropdown to state and bind that state with dropdown component with value property (value = selected state") then it will select value.